# How to extract averages from a matrix with x possible groups

Tags: r

Let's say that I have the following example data set:

```
df1 = 
ID    Group_Type    Units
 1       A           10
 2       A           12
 3       A           17
 4       B            6
 5       B            9
 6       D           23
 7       D           16
 8       D           21
 9       G           40
10       G           31
```

The group type can potentially be any letter between A and Z in the English alphabet. Is there a way to simultaneously detect that groups A, B, D, and G are present (or any present groups), and then to average the units for each group, and assign the entire result to a matrix? I'm thinking that it would look something like this:

```
      [,1]
[1,]   13
[2,]   7.5
[3,]   20
[4,]   35
```

([1,]=A, and so on... [,1]=Average per group)

I know how to do these tasks separately, but I don't know how to combine it into a piece of manageable code. I've recently used table, unlist, and grep to pick out words in a data frame, but I can't figure much out past that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that 'df1' is a 'data.frame'.  If it is a 'matrix' (which I doubt)

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1$Units <- as.numeric(df1$Units)
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Group_Type) %>%
   summarise(Units=mean(Units))
#    Group_Type Units
#1          A  13.0
#2          B   7.5
#3          D  20.0
#4          G  35.5
```

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(Units~Group_Type, df1, FUN=mean, na.action=NULL)
#  Group_Type Units
#1          A  13.0
#2          B   7.5
#3          D  20.0
#4          G  35.5
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Units=mean(Units)), Group_Type]
#    Group_Type Units
#1:          A  13.0
#2:          B   7.5
#3:          D  20.0
#4:          G  35.5
```

For the `dplyr`, `data.table` and `aggregate`, you can use the option `na.rm=TRUE` to remove the `NA` values from the `mean` calculation. i.e. `mean(Units, na.rm=TRUE)` for `dplyr/data.table` and `...,FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)` for the `aggregate`

Or `sqldf`.  The `avg` will remove the `NA/null` values by default

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select Group_Type,
        avg(Units) as Units 
        from df1 
        group by Group_Type',
        method = "raw")
 #   Group_Type Units
 #1          A  13.0
 #2          B   7.5
 #3          D  20.0
 #4          G  35.5
```

Suppose if is a single missing value in 'Units' for a 'Group_Type' and want the output to be `NA`.

```
 df1$Units[3] <- NA
 sqldf('select Group_Type,
           case when count(Units) = count(*) 
                then avg(Units) 
                else null 
                end as Units
           from df1 
           group by Group_Type',
           method="raw")
 #   Group_Type Units
 #1          A  <NA>
 #2          B   7.5
 #3          D  20.0
 #4          G  35.5
```

Comment: I appreciate the options! I'm using base R for now, but I'm interested in dplyr for sure. Is there one that you prefer for this type of data manipulation?

Comment: @Adam the `data.table` and `dplyr` versions are fast compared to `aggregate`.

Comment: I will bear that in mind, thank you. Is there any way to keep NA values in my result if NA values do exist in the Units section? I have tried turning na.rm to FALSE, but it did not work.

Comment: @Adam The default option in `mean` will be `na.rm=FALSE`. So, if there is a single NA value for Units per Group_Type, that mean value will be NA.  Why do you need it that way?  For `aggregate`, you may need `na.action=NULL`

Comment: I will be installing dplyr here momentarily-- it has been recommended to me a few times now, and I finally have decent enough internet to get things to work for me. na.action=NULL worked.

I have to multiply each average by a corresponding frequency in another object-- without the NAs for some groups (which I do not have averages for), it gives me an artificially high frequency for groups that should have been NA in terms of contribution.

Comment: I appreciate all of the help-- in only 17 lines I wrote a block of code that is going to save everybody in my lab a lot of time with data analyses for one of our most commonly asked questions. My first real program!

Comment: @Adam Glad to help you with your question.